# scrollBehavior affect in the entire pages in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I tried to make a website in nuxt like mobile phones,So I used this code

```
 scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.path === '/' || to.path === '/explore') {
            savedPosition = false
        }
    },
```

in nuxt.config.js

but happen What I am not expected when the user in for example scroll position = 100 in page a and try go to page B it will be same position = 100 like page a and this What I don't want it is same as when the user scroll in one page and going to position scroll 100, and when the routing to any other page in the app it is same position scroll

**What I want**

I want each page scroll position to be separate from the other

I use keep alive in my app